# SharePoint designer workflow to lookup email in another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list that stores email address.
I would like to use send email activity workflow to pick up emails from
the list based on some comparison fields.How to set it up?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naijacoder,

You can use the *Send an Email* action to do this. When editing the action details use the directory control to open up the *Select Users* dialog. In that dialog double click the "Workflow Lookup for a User..." selection. Set the

- 'Data source' as the list with the email address
- 'Field from source' as the email address column
- 'Field' as the column from the second list that you will contain the value you search for (ex: *emplid*)
- 'Value' as the value to look for the entry in the email list (ex: *Current Item: emplid*)

That should send the email to whatever email address corresponds to the unique value you searched for.