# Email Multiple Recipients in Related List

Tags: designer-workflow, multiple-values, send-email

I have a discussion list, and a categories list.  In the Categories list, there's a column for Moderator, which is a Person or Group.  In the Discussions list, the column for Categories Allows multiple values.

This way, a person can start a discussion, and assign it more than one category.  But I cannot get a workflow to email multiple moderators to a discussion.

If I uncheck Allow multiple values for Categories in a Discussion item, my workflow works - I followed the basic documentation (here: [SharePoint designer workflow to lookup email in another list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75502/sharepoint-designer-workflow-to-lookup-email-in-another-list)).  But as soon as I change the settings for category column to Allow multiple values, the workflow don't work.  I don't think I can use Sharepoint groups, because the recipients will be determined by which categories are assigned to that particular discussion item.

I am rather new to this.  We're on Sharepoint Online, and I'm using Sharepoint Designer.

Any help will be hugely appreciated!
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Matthew, I'm sorry to tell you this, but this is one of SharePoint's limitations. The multi select option on fields tend to mess thing up. For this reason we are often forced to resort to archaic methods like having fields such as Category 1, Category2, Category3... You get the picture. 
The only way to make it work would be a custom solution, maybe hosted from Azure, that can inspect the Category field data and compile the list of recipients for your workflow to use. This would be a complex solution.

Comment: Hello Cornelius,

Wow, that's not what I expected!  I've been playing around with trying to pass all of the assigned moderators to a text field, separated by semicolons, then pass that to an email address field.  But I have been unable to do so.  I thought there might a looping process which could accomplish this.  But it sounds like you're suggesting we forego this feature?

Thank you,
Matthew